# How to optimize the function query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query that has an index on the where clause column, but MySQL doesn't pick up the index; I'm not sure what the issue is. Is there any way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT 
  cart_medicine_detail._id AS _id, 
  cart_medicine_detail.cartId AS cartId, 
  cart_medicine_detail.medicineId AS medicineId, 
  cart_medicine_detail.distributorId AS distributorId, 
  cart_medicine_detail.quantity AS quantity, 
  cart_medicine_detail.name AS name, 
  cart_medicine_detail.itemCode AS itemCode, 
  cart_medicine_detail.dealType AS dealType, 
  cart_medicine_detail.reason AS reason, 
  cart_medicine_detail.isDeleted AS isDeleted, 
  cart_medicine_detail.actualPrice AS actualPrice, 
  cart_medicine_detail.source AS source, 
  from_unixtime(
    (
      cart_medicine_detail.createdTimestamp / 1000
    )
  ) AS createdTimestamp, 
  from_unixtime(
    (
      cart_medicine_detail.updatedTimestamp / 1000
    )
  ) AS updatedTimestamp, 
  cart_medicine_detail.medicineCategory AS medicineCategory, 
  cart_medicine_detail.medicineSubCategory AS medicineSubCategory 
FROM 
  saveo_prod.cart_medicine_detail 
WHERE 
  cart_medicine_detail.createdTimestamp >= unix_timestamp(
    date_add(
      now(6), 
      INTERVAL -7 day
    )
  )
```

explain plan

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cart_medicine_detail
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: idx_createdTimestamp
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 12031730
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where
```

Please  share your thoughts; it would be helpful for a large amount of data.

Comment: The index might not help, because the MySQL optimizer will skip using the index and just use a table-scan as it is doing now, if enough rows satisfy the condition anyway. You can try to use [FORCE INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) if you think MySQL is making that choice prematurely.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked. Are there any other options?

Comment: There's nothing to change. Your query has a single predicate comparing an indexed column to a constant expression. It doesn't use the index by default because apparently a large proportion of your rows match the condition. If you want it to use the index by default, use a condition that matches fewer rows.

Comment: and what about CTE does that resolve the performance issue?

Comment: Why do you think CTE will help?

Comment: i thought it have high readablity.

Comment: can you give me the suggestion to avoid this issues cuz it causing load

Comment: I did give two suggestions: `FORCE INDEX`, and change the query condition to match fewer rows. The problem is not the query. The problem is that you have a lot of data. The only other things you can do is get a more powerful server, or split up the data over multiple servers.

Comment: now i got you thanks i'll spilt and run it as a chunk

Comment: If you've just inserted a whole mess of rows to your table, you may, or may not, benefit from running [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) before you run your query.  It certainly won't hurt anything, and it will help the query planner make a good choice about whether it's faster to use an index scan or table scan for the particular date range you want. CTEs make little or no performance difference; the query planner just folds them in.

Comment: What percent of the table was in the last 7 days?  If more than about 20%, it is faster to ignore the index.

Comment: You tried it without the index and with FORCE INDEX.  Which was faster?

Comment: What data type is `createdTimestamp`?  `createdTimestamp / 1000` is not compatible with comparing to a unix_timestamp.

Comment: no  force index  not speeding up the performance @RickJames

Comment: let me add the datatype

Comment: i will add the both explain plan and data type too please check above once.

Comment: @O.Jones i'll try your suggestion let me check the performance

Comment: Can you guys suggest your thoughts please it would be useful to me to understand the situation better, thanks.

Comment: @meritonissac - Summary of suggestions:  Study BillKarwin's Comments; ignore CTE; don't worry about whether it uses the index, instead worry about whether it is fast enough.

Comment: yeah, I have read it, I wanted to know your opinion too so if it same as before, I'm checking the possibilities as BillKarwin's comments.